# Make height:auto in table with fixed column

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to  set the height of rows in the table to be as the height of the first column in the row if it's position is absolute?

It of course works if I do not use 'position:absolute' (or 'position:fixed') but I need first and last columns to be fixed.

In the example you can see that first column's rows are overlapping. I would like the first and second rows to fit the text inside completely.

http://jsfiddle.net/ujwz4htg/27/

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

td:first-child {
  white-space: intial;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td:last-child {
  white-space: initial;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  right: 160px;
  top: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
}

div {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-left: 5em;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.long {
  background: pink;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Row Row Row Row</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDsdasdFGHJKLZXCVBsdfsdfNM</td>
      <td>LAST</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1 222222 333333333</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDsdasdFGHJKLZXCVBsdfsdfNM</td>
      <td>LAST</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDsdasdFGHJKLZXCVBsdfsdfNM</td>
      <td>LAST</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDsdasdFGHJKLZXCVBsdfsdfNM</td>
      <td>LAST</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDsdasdFGHJKLZXCVBsdfsdfNM</td>
      <td>LAST</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is a Javascript solution fine?

Comment: Yes is it. I am using angular for the whole project.

Comment: angularjs? share the controller?

Comment: Yes, angularjs. So far this page does not have any controller. I am just trying to draw the table, but I can incorporate solution to the controller later on.